# C++ friend a function in a separate namespace

Tags: c++, function, namespaces, friend

I'm having issues with my code.

I have a class called Engine:

```
// Engine.h
#include "SaveLoad.h"

class Engine {
    friend void SaveLoad::save(Engine& engine);
    friend void SaveLoad::load(Engine& engine);
public:
...
```

The concern here is I want the functions save() and load() to be able to access and manipulate Engine's private data members freely, which is why I friended them. SaveLoad is actually a namespace in another header file, as shown below:

```
// SaveLoad.h
#include "Engine.h"

namespace SaveLoad {
    void save(Engine& engine);
    void load(Engine& engine);
}
```

All seems fine so far. Next I call the load() function from Engine's constructor to load the application's saved data:

```
// Engine.cpp
Engine::Engine(...) {
    ...
    SaveLoad::load(*this);
}
```

I've passed the Engine to the load() function so load() can update Engine's data members when the application is launched.

After compiling, I get literally 22 error messages, some seemingly absurd and others just down right confusing. Some of these errors are:

- 'Engine' undeclared identifier -- saveload.h
- 'save' illegal use of type 'void' -- saveload.h
- 'load' illegal use of type 'void' -- saveload.h
- 'SaveLoad::save' not a function -- engine.h
- 'SaveLoad::load' not a function -- engine.h
- 'SaveLoad' is not a class or a namespace -- engine.h

And directed at the SaveLoad::load(*this) line:

- term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 argument -- engine.cpp

I'm guessing this has something to do with the fact that I'm trying to friend functions that are part of a namespace instead of a class or it has something to do with the #includes, but I'm really out of ideas when it comes to playing with the code.

Comment: does your header files has include guards?

Comment: @sfk92fksdf Yes all header files use #pragma once, which has always been the default replacement for inclusion guards.

Comment: You have circular `#include`s. Don't `#include "Engine.h"` in SaveLoad.h - it's sufficient to provide a forward declaration for `Engine` there, as in `class Engine;`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It worked! Do you mind explaining why a circular include was ruining it and why a forward declaration fixed the problem? I don't understand what the problem was.

Comment: Engine.cpp includes, say, Engine.h. Which includes SaveLoad.h. Which includes Engine.h again - but thanks to include guards (which I assume you have), most of the header is skipped. Then SaveLoad.h mentions the name `Engine` - but the compiler hasn't seen its declaration yet.